# sql server 2000 compare detail sum to total amount

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I need a little help. I have an invoice table and and invoice detail table. I pulled the data I care about from the invoice details table to a temp table (for other calculations). I need to find the invoices where the sum of the detail lines do not equal the total cost in the invoice table. Here is my code:

```
Create table #inv_det (
invco varchar(6),
invno int,
invtot money,
invpd int);

Insert into #inv_det (invco,invno,invtot,invpd)
Select invd_inv_co, invd_inv_no, invd_total_cost, invd_glpd_no 
from invdet 
inner join invoice on invd_inv_co=inv_co and invd_inv_no=inv_no 
where inv_dt>=cast('10-01-13 00:00:00' as datetime) and inv_dt<=cast('10-31-13 11:59:59' as datetime);
```

Here is my query:

```
Select invco, invno from #inv_det 
inner join invoice on invco=inv_co and invno=inv_no 
where inv_dt>=cast('10-01-13 00:00:00' as datetime) 
  and inv_dt<=cast('10-31-13 11:59:59' as datetime) 
having sum(invtot)<>inv_total_amt
group by invco, invno;
```

When I run my query I get "Server: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'."

I hope I explained my goal well enough. Hopefully someone can point out what I'm missing. I've tried many variations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY` and `HAVING` are the wrong way around in your SQL

Answer (score 2):

`GROUP BY`should come before `HAVING`like:

```
Select invco,invno from #inv_det inner join invoice on
invco=inv_co and invno=inv_no where inv_dt>=cast('10-01-13 00:00:00' as datetime)
and inv_dt<=cast('10-31-13 11:59:59' as datetime) 
group by invco, invno
having sum(invtot)<>inv_total_amt;
```

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  Could have sworn I did that first.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: @user2951171 Happy to help :) Please consider accepting my answer so the question gets marked as solved.